# Turning a chain of foreach's for inserting elements from a list into another list into linq

Tags: c#, linq, list, foreach

I've been at it for a couple of hours and the only conclusion I achieved is that I need to pick up a good book about Linq.

So here's the deal: I have three lists of objects of the following classes (I'll refer to them as "parent lists" from now on:

```
    public class State
    {
        public int IdState {get; set;}
        public string NameState {get; set;}
        private IList<City> cityList = new List<City>();

        public void AddCity(City city)
        {
            cityList.Add(city);
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        public int IdCity { get; set; }
        public string NameCity { get; set; }
        public int IdState { get; set; }
        private IList<Company> companyList = new List<Company>();

        public void AddCompany(Company company)
        {
            companyList.Add(company);
        }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public int IdCompany { get; set; }
        public string NameCompany { get; set; }
        public int IdCity { get; set; }
    }
```

I think from here is pretty straight forward to explain what I want: A single list of States, of which cityList is populated with the appropriate cities in that state and each companyList list in each City is populated with the companies in that city. In other words, a list of states which each state branches into its cities and then each city branches into the companies in them.

So, my parent lists are:

```
    private List<State> finalList; //This is the "parent list supreme" which I'll send to the client-side
    private List<City> cityList; //Auxiliary
    private List<Company> companyList; //Auxiliary; this one does not exist in the actual code but I'm putting it here for simplification purposes
```

It really doesn't matter how but thanks to linq "magic", I'm able to fill up those lists with the proper states, cities and companies, however, I can't figure out how to fill up the proper cities and companies into State.cityList and City.companyList through link. As it stands, I'm using a very ugly chain of foreach's:

```
        foreach (State state in finalList)
        {
            foreach (City city in cityList)
            {
                if (city.IdState == state.IdState)
                {
                    state.AddCity(city);

                    foreach (Company company in companyList)
                    {
                        if (company.idCity == city.IdCity)
                            city.AddCompany(company);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ugly, right? So, how do I go about achieving the same thing with linq? I think maybe an even more valid question: is it worth using linq in this case (it all points to "yes" but figures...)?

BTW: this way works just as I expect

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to achieve.  Is finalList prepopulated with states, and you are just trying to insert the cities and companies into the children?  Or is it reversed?

Comment: In your example code, this part is confusing: `if (line.idCity == city.IdCity)` as it doesn't seem to make sense within the context of the parent foreach.  Neither line nor city is being changed within the foreach, so if that is correct, shouldn't it be moved outside the foreach since it will always be true or always be false for all iterations of companyList?

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thanks for pointing that out, it was a "residual code", given that in the actual code I don't use a support list for companies. Edited to comply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're logically doing here is a Join operation.  Your current code is actually finding all possible pairs of cities and states and then filering only the pairs that match.  You could represent that in LINQ, but you wouldn't want to.  There are more efficient ways of performing a Join that only generate the exact pairs that you need to begin with.  The LINQ `Join` operator leverages this.

Your code boils down to two different `Join` calls, and then an iteration over each result that performs the mutation of the objects based on the query.

```
var stateCityPairs = from state in finalList
                        join city in cityList
                        on state.IdState equals city.IdState
                        select new { state, city };

foreach (var pair in stateCityPairs)
    pair.state.AddCity(pair.city);


var cityCompanyPairs = from city in cityList
                        join company in companyList
                        on city.IdCity equals company.IdCity
                        select new { city, company };

foreach (var pair in cityCompanyPairs)
    pair.city.AddCompany(pair.company);
```

While this is actually a tad more code, this will perform quite a bit better for larger collections, and also semantically represents what the intent of your code is.

Comment: Thanks Servy, I'll try as soon as I get home and I'll let you know

Comment: I've already tried this code in my dummy application and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Naturally.

Comment: @Servy As expected, it took some fine tuning to place the code into the real project (as a matter of fact, I didn't have to alter your code at all). I'd kiss you if I could man. Great job. And nice tip on the foreach vs ForEach either. Once again, many thanks and I suppose it's time to some Linq books. Any suggestions?

Comment: @S.O. Not really.  [Jon Skeet's blog series](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/02/23/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-45-conclusion-and-list-of-posts.aspx) on reimplementing it is very interesting, and he of course has a number of other posts surrounding LINQ and other interesting topics, but some of that's a bit more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I added 2 methods in the City and State class. It would be easier if the lists were public though :

```
public void AddCities(List<City> cities)
{
    cityList.Concat(cities);
}

public void AddCompanies(List<Company> companies)
{
    companyList.Concat(companies);
}
```

You can use the aggregator you want. I normally prefer Union because it doesn't add doubles but I guess it doesn't really matter in your case.

Hers's how I would do it in Linq :

```
cityList.ForEach(ci => ci.AddCompanies(companyList.Where(co => co.IdCity == ci.IdCity).ToList()));
finalList.ForEach(s => s.AddCities(cityList.Where(ci => ci.IdState == s.IdState).ToList()));
```

I added the companies to the proper cities first and then I added all the cities in the correct state.
If you need more explication about this code, feel free to ask.

Comment: 1) Your use of `Concat` in `AddCities` isn't right.  Concat creates a new sequence, which you just drop on the floor.  Instead accept an `IEnumerable` as input (might as well, to allow for deferred execution) and call `AddRange` inside of the method. 2) `ForEach` isn't really LINQ, and isn't any better than just using a `foreach` loop. 3) You are doing what the OP is doing and finding all pairs and then filtering.  That's *much* less efficient than doing a `Join`.

Comment: @Servy `AddRange` is on `List<T>`, not `IList<T>`, so it won't be available here.  This does not change the validity of any of your points.

Comment: @cadrell0 True enough.  This is why I dislike it when people store such fields as `IList`; I'd much rather see it stored as `List`.  Thanks for pointing that out though; I did miss that.

Comment: @Servy Actually, declaring them as IList gave me a lot of trouble before 'cause they just won't give support to linq extension methods, I ended up using List for all of them. BTW, I'm about to test your code in the actual solution. Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

Well with LINQ, you would want to convert your private ILists to public ILists (Or List or IEnumerable or IQueryable) so you can set them directly.

Assuming finalList is prepopulated with the States already:

```
var finalList=finalList
    .Select(fl=>new State
    {
        fl.IdState,
        fl.NameState,
        cityList=cityList.Where(cl=>cl.IdState==fl.IdState).Select(cl=>
            new City
            {
                cl.IdCity,
                cl.NameCity,
                cl.IdState,
                companyList=companyList.Where(comp=>
                    comp.IdState==cl.IdState && comp.IdCity==cl.IdCity)
            }
    });
```

Comment: That's not needed at all.  You simply perform a query to see what gets added, and then add them all through a `foreach`, as I showed in my answer.  While you certainly *could* provide a means of adding multiple values at a time, that's certainly not *required*.

Comment: I didn't say it was required, only that he would want to.  He said he wanted to do it using LINQ, and forEach isn't LINQ, it's a method of IEnumerable.

Comment: Then this isn't an answer to the question, it is at best a comment.  `foreach` isn't a method of anything, it's a language keyword.  You're correct, it's not LINQ.  You would be using it in addition to a LINQ query, as is done with a large percentage of LINQ queries in general.

Comment: ForEach as you used it is not a keyword, it's a method of List (Sorry, I thought it was IEnumerable, but it is actually List).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx  foreach as he used it is a keyword.

Comment: I did not use the List's `ForEach` method at all.  I just used the `foreach` keyword.  I never use `ForEach`.  I'll let Eric Lippert [explain why](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I got confused between your answer and fokasu's.